# Angular Material table with right-to-left direction

Tags: angular, angular-material, right-to-left, sticky

I am using angular material 7.1.1 version. I have a table with horizontal scrolling and sticky columns.

It works fine, but when I try to change the direction to display from right to left (my table data display Hebrew text so it must be `rtl`) the behavior is really strange.

I created an example to show it in stackblitz: [material-table-right-to-left](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjn6ga-qqstaj?file=app%2Ftable-example.css)

Comment: What do you mean by 'really strange'? What do you want the behavior to be?

Comment: The behaviour seems ok, because your 2 stiky columns are to the right

Comment: the numbers disappear when scrolling, you can see the header only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me, too, I've upgraded my chrome and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the whole angular materials rtl
by adding to css page:
  * {
    direction: rtl;
  }

hope it will help.
regards.
Yehuda.